# Converting C to MIPS by hand

Tags: c, assembly, mips32

I'm trying to figure out how to convert some C declarations to MIPS. I have:

```
main()
{
  int ia = 7;
  int ib = 0x23;
  int ic,id,ie,ig;

  ia = 0x1234;
  ib = ia;
  ic = ia + ib;
  id = ic | ib & 17;
  ie = ~ig;
  ig = (ia - ib) ^ (ic + id);   
}
```

If I just assume the .data is already declared and focus on the .text part, what I started trying to do was to convert the hex values to decimal to use as immediates then store those values like this:

```
li  $s0, 7
sw  $s0, ia

li  $s0, 35
sw  $s0, ib

li  $s0, 4660
sw  $s0, ia
```

I feel like this is probably wrong though. What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? Looks OK to me.

Comment: It just seemed like converting from hex to decimal then using that number as immediates was kind of cheating and there was probably a better way to do it. Maybe not though, I'm not sure.

Comment: You don't need to convert to decimal assuming your assembler understands hex and most do. You might be expected to declare your variables on the stack though, as they are locals. In that case you have to address them relative to `$sp`

Comment: So say I wanted to store 0x23 into `ib: .word 0x00000000`, could I do `lb  $s0, 0x23` then `sb $s0, ib`? I'm confused about how to put the hex into a register.

Comment: You can declare your immediate constants in any format the assembler understands.  You can surely use hex, although it might or might not use the 0x syntax.

Comment: I'm using QtSpim right now. So far when I use an immediate it converts decimal to hex. I tried 0x to hex directly and it gave me an error.

Comment: Note: Assembler does not have a concept of types (well, those for current CPUs), so there is no need to translate **declarations**. However, what you showed are actually **definitions**.

Comment: Ok got it working, thanks.